# Unable to send an email using PHPmailer in Drupal 7

Tags: smtp, drupal-7, google-cloud-console

My website https://www.smcin.com/ created in drupal 7 and hosted in google cloud console. I am using PHPmailer smtp module to send email through website using port 25. But not mail has been triggered and give error

> "test e-mail has NOT been sent to xxxxxxxx@yahoo.com. You should check
>   the logs for error messages."

On logs only this message has been shown:

```
MESSAGE:    Error sending e-mail (from xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.xxx to xxxxxxxx@yahoo.com).
SEVERITY:   error.
```

I also tried other ports (80, 465, 2525 ) and server (gmail, my official webmail) but nothing work.
I wasted lots of time but no solution found.

Comment: Its not look like a drupal issue , but you have to check web hosting configuration if it allow you to send mails , did you tried a simple test with `mail()` function ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear as to which Google Cloud Platform service you are using.

Assuming that you're using Compute Engine, please see [Sending email from an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail).

**NB** "Port 25 is always blocked and can't be used"

You should be able to configure it to use e.g. 465.

You may continue to have challenges in showing a good reputation for your instances' IP addresses.